# XML View in Android Studio Dolphin not loading after update from Chipmunk

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

When ever there is an error in xml file the view for the reference in Android Studio gets invisible its very hard to work without having a view reference. I have invalided the cache and restart android studio several times still not working it is only happening after updating to Dolphin from chipmunk

Answer (score 1):

**I had the same problem with android studio and tried all these ways**

1. closing the project and deleting the project.xml file in the
   .idea\codeStyles\
2. upgrade and downgrade the AGP version. AGP = Android Gradle Plugin
3. Invalidate Caches and Restart
4. deleted this folder %APPDATA%\Google\AndroidStudio*.
5. inspection profiles folder under the project's idea folder and upgrade the Gradle version.

**But all not working**

So I downgraded Android Version to Android Studio Chipmunk (2021.2.1) and It working now fine, you can download it from

> https://developer.android.com/studio/archive

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to update your `Gradle` version first from Project Structure

[image]

Then **Restart** your system and that's it

**I hope help**

Comment: It doesn't work for me.

Comment: @StanleyKo I meant restart your computer

Comment: Did you manage to find a fix for the problem? @Dkathayat1

Comment: @Mosericko not yet I had to downgrade the studio until its stable or have a fix